# Center align the XTicks labels with each bar on the histogram plot in Matlab and provide spacing in between

Tags: matlab, alignment, histogram, center

Right now my XTicks labels do not align with the bars. I need help in aligning them. My code is as follows:

```
x = randi([0 253], 1, 100);
figure;
hist(x,7)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'1,S', '2,TS', '3,H1', '4,H2', '5,H3', 
'6,H4','7,H5'})
xlabel('Category of Storm')
ylabel('Number of Storm Occurrences')
```

[image: Unaligned Histogram Plot Link]

Answer (score 0):

First place the desired number of ticks on the right position (and then label them):

```
x = randi([0 253], 1, 100);
figure;
hist(x,7)
xlabel('Category of Storm')
ylabel('Number of Storm Occurrences')
%%%
h = 253/7;
xticks(h/2:h:253-h/2)
%%%
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'1,S', '2,TS', '3,H1', '4,H2', '5,H3', '6,H4','7,H5'})
```

[image]